# Is there a "standard" format for Dynamic DNS updates?

Tags: dns, standards

Is there a "standard" format for DDNS client/server communications? I'm considering creating a client, but I wasn't sure if there was a preferred way of sending the requests. Sockets, XMS, JSON, etc?

This is pretty subjective and I'm sorry. Just looking for advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic DNS is actually a standardized protocol defined in the DNS system in the first place; so you actually send DNS packets to do it.  See [RFC2136](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2136.txt) for details.  But really you probably want a library to link against, rather than write the packets yourself.